# How to retrieve the push id value

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In this code I need to save the data in firebase database as (Registration Data1 then UID then push id)

```
btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
                
  FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
  String uid = firebaseUser.getUid();
  databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Registration 
  Data1").child(uid).push();


  String sp1 = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
  String sp2 = spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString();
  String sp3 = spinner3.getSelectedItem().toString();

  Data DBdata = new Data(sp1,sp2,sp3,uid);
  databaseReference.setValue(DBdata);
  //Toast.makeText(this,"Data Added",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();'''
```

And in this code I need to retrieve the data in recyclerview

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Registration Data1");
mDBListener = databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
 @Override
 public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    
    
  for (DataSnapshot teacherSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
   Data DB = teacherSnapshot.getValue(Data.class);
   DB.setKey(teacherSnapshot.getKey());
   mTeachers.add(DB);
    
    
}
 mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
 mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
    
@Override
public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
 Toast.makeText(Public.this, databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
});
```

The question is how to retrieve the data under push id without make .child(UID)?

Comment: Tthe code looks fine to me at a first glance. When you run the code you shared, which line doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: When i run the application i  fill the data and click on "save" button, it save the data in firebase as this code: databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Registration 
  Data1").child(uid).push();      But when i click on "retrieve" button it doesn't retrieve any data

Comment: Hmmm... that seems unexpected from you shared. The loop over `dataSnapshot.getChildren()` is key here, but that looks good to me. If you put a breakpoint on `for (DataSnapshot teacherSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())` and on `Data DB = teacherSnapshot.getValue(Data.class);`, and then run in a debugger, does it reach either/both of them?